# What to use? "that found that" or "found that"

Tags: grammar

> A good illustration of this is provided by a recent survey conducted
>   by the British government **that found that** 26% of students...

What to use? **that found that** or **found that**?

Comment: The second instance of the relativiser ***that*** is optional in your context, but syntactically you *need* the first one (because its target referent ***a recent survey*** is an *indirect object,* not the primary *subject* of the sentence). There's nothing particularly unusual or "clumsy" about having two instances of ***that*** in close proximity.

Comment: Or, *which found that....* if you what to avoid  the double that.

Answer (score -1):

The double "that" is awkward.

I would remove the the first "that" as being unneeded.

> **A recent survey conducted by the British government found that 26% of students...**